# XElement.Element returning null for newly created element

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement

I am using `XElement` to create an `XMLDocument` which is used in a hierarchical WPF treeview. If I create a new element with :

```
    x_element = new XElement("node",
    new XElement("tree_id", strData[0]),
    new XElement("sys_id", dpl.DepSysId),
    new XElement("part_id", strData[8]),
    new XElement("make", strData[6]),
    new XElement("model", strData[5]),
    new XElement("level", strData[2]));
```

I then need to add attributes to "node" so I tried:

```
   XElement temp_el = x_element.Element("node"); // This is returning null
   temp_el.SetAttributeValue("title", strData[7] + " " + strData[6] + " " + strData[5]);
   temp_el.SetAttributeValue("canEdit", "False");
   temp_el.SetAttributeValue("status", nStatus.ToString());
   temp_el.SetAttributeValue("qty", strData[13]);
   temp_el.SetAttributeValue("part", strData[8]);
```

In the above code temp_el is null, but I can see in the debugger that x_element contains the following :

```
<node>
  <tree_id>82</tree_id>
  <sys_id>82</sys_id>
  <part_id>169</part_id>
  <make>ST Panel</make>
  <model>Logical Pure 16 tube Collector</model>
  <level>0</level>
</node>
```

To work around this I have used the following:

```
   foreach (XElement temp_el in x_element.DescendantsAndSelf())
   {
       if (temp_el.Name == "node")
       {
           temp_el.SetAttributeValue("title", strData[7] + " " + strData[6] + " " + strData[5]);
           temp_el.SetAttributeValue("canEdit", "False");
           temp_el.SetAttributeValue("status", nStatus.ToString());
           temp_el.SetAttributeValue("qty", strData[13]);
           temp_el.SetAttributeValue("part", strData[8]);
           break;
       }
   }
```

Whilst the above works I am just curious as to why I am getting null returned. Is my workaround the best way of doing this?

Regards.

Comment: The answers address what's going wrong, but in terms of the best way: the constructor for `new XElement` allows you to also add `new XAttribute`s along with the `new XElement`s you are already adding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined your XElement like this:

```
x_element = new XElement("node", /* child nodes */);
```

Where `"node"` is the name of the `XElement` you are creating, and the following parameters are its children.

By using `x_element.Node("node")`, you are trying to get the child node named `"node"`, and there isn't such a child node.
`x_element` **itself** is the node named "node".
`DescendantsAndSelf` worked because it includes `x_element` (hence "AndSelf"), but you don't need this either because you already have the node.

So you can change your second code snippet to this:

```
x_element.SetAttributeValue("title", strData[7] + " " + strData[6] + " " + strData[5]);
x_element.SetAttributeValue("canEdit", "False");
// etc.
```

(BTW, you can also add the Attributes in the constructor)

Comment: Thank you for your reply and explanation, it has really helped in clarifying my understanding of XElements.

Answer (score 1):

Because with your first `temp_el`,

```
XElement temp_el = x_element.Element("node");
```

You used to get nodes which is not treated to be an Element of x_element.

It was treated as its root. However, with the second one,

```
x_element.DescendantsAndSelf()`
```

You used this `XElement` Method which treat node itself as an element.

> [XContainer.Elements Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342765.aspx) - *Returns a collection of the child elements of this element or document, in document order.*
>
> [XElement.DescendantsAndSelf Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346989.aspx) - *Returns a collection of elements that contain **this element, and all descendant elements of this element**, in document order.*

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue I used Descendants(). Here is my code snippet

```
public void UpdateEnquiry([FromBody]XElement UpdatePurchaseOrder)
        {
            var obj = XElement.Parse(UpdatePurchaseOrder.ToString());
            var ii = (from v in obj.Descendants() select new { v.Value }).ToList() ;
         }
```